# google-cloud-storage .Net 3.5 not support?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there anyway to use google-cloud-storage APIs in VS 2008?

It shows Google.Apis.dll was built by newer version so can not run on my project when i trying to build my project.

I was trying to test the APIs from Google Cloud Storage.

```html
var googleClientService = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
googleClientService.ApiKey = "ABcdefghUSftzxcvbnmEhLmGcZnfcE_12345678";

var storageService = new StorageService(googleClientService);
var getRequest = storageService.Buckets.List("demotest");
```

Comment: I hope it is not a real api key ;)

Comment: haha, it's not. I type it myself. That's why it contains 'abcdefg' and '12345678'.

Answer (score 1):

Sorrry, I don't believe there's a pre-built .NET client available for early versions of .NET. The source code of the library is public, though. You could perhaps try and build it, if you feel like a challenge. Alternately, the library is simply a small wrapper around a public, RESTful API. You could also invoke the Google Cloud Storage API directly with standard HTTP libraries, although you'll have to handle authorization.

Comment: I only found how to get the library by using NuGet and it didn't download source code, only .dll files. Do you know where to find source code?